# Convert unsigned 64-bit decimal to Java double

Tags: java

I'm being sent an unsigned 64-bit decimal value and am required to store it as a `double`, which of course is signed.

Realizing I will lose a little bit of precision with values that make use of the most significant bit, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Perhaps there is a way to manipulate the unsigned value using `Double.doubleToLongBits()` or the `BigDecimal` class?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "unsigned 64-bit decimal value"?

Comment: Will you need to be able to mathematically manipulate the value as a `double`, or you are simply using the `double` as a means to store the raw bits?

Comment: Right -- "unsigned 64-bit decimal" does not compute.

Comment: Do you mean 64-bit *integer* (`long`), or BigDecimal?  They're two entirely different things.

Comment: It is described as a 64-bit floating point. I am receiving other types of values, too, and they are supposedly unsigned. Is it unusual to be working with unsigned decimals?

Comment: You're making less and less sense.

Comment: In the end I need to have a double, because it was what an API call requires.

Comment: "64-bit floating point", in most universes, would be `double`.  Unsigned 64-bit fixed-point integer would be `unsigned long long` in C (at least on some platforms), but Java doesn't support unsigned so you'd have to play some minor games.

Comment: Yes, I can manipulate it.

Comment: You really need to find out what sort of data you have.  Probably you should review a textbook section on data representations.

Comment: Let's start again.  Where is the data coming from?  Where does it need to go?  What does the destination need to do with the data?

Comment: @Hot Licks, then it's quite possible the value IS actually coming across signed, and only the other, non-decimal data types (integer, long, etc.) are going to be unsigned. If what I described in my question sounds highly unusual, perhaps I was actually told the wrong thing and ran with it.

Comment: Just about anything is possible.  But so far you've told us *nothing* about the format of the data, so there's little we can do to help you.

Comment: The data will be coming across a socket, the values (and they vary in datatype) will all eventually be converted to doubles and used in an API call.

Comment: What datatypes, specifically?  Without knowing that, there is no meaningful answer to this question.

Comment: I was told that all the values are unsigned. I know for instance, that at byte 40, I can find a 32-bit unsigned int. 4 bytes later, at byte 44, I can find a 64-bit floating point (which I believe is unsigned). etc. etc. I have the outline of where to find what kind of value. Do I need to provide the whole thing? It's long and trivial.  Unfortunately, I have no way of seeing sample values at the moment, but like I said, I know at what position I can expect to find which value type.

Comment: Specifically: unsigned 16 bit int, unsigned 8-bit int, unsigned 64-bit int, unsigned 32-bit floating point, unsigned 64-bit floating point

Comment: The only answer we can give is "for each data format, define an appropriate conversion routine".

Comment: "int" here is used losely

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, OK I was hoping maybe there was a standard unsigned 64-bit floating point representation (not in Java of course). I have already developed ways to convert the integer values per my understanding.

Comment: There isn't any such thing as an unsigned floating point format. All the IEEE floating point formats have a sign bit. Java has ways to convert a 64-bit value to a double, and to turn a long into its unsigned 64-bit String representation, and to turn a String into a double, or to turn a String into a BigDecimal. But it isn't clear which of these things you want.

Comment: @DavidConrad - Of course, technically one *could* define an unsigned floating point format if one wished.  It would be an odd bird, though, and it would be incumbent on the provider to supply a detailed specification.

Answer (score 2):

If you really mean "unsigned 64-bit binary value in a long", you could just convert that long to a double (with a cast), and then, if the long was negative, add 2<sup>64</sup> as a double (18446744073709551616.0)

If, on the other hand, you really mean "decimal integer that might overflow 63 bits when converted to binary", you can just convert the string directly to double with `DOUBLE.parseDouble`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "unsigned 64-bit binary value in a long", then Guava can help:

```
import com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong;
...
long value = -1L; // max unsigned long = 2^64-1
double dValue = UnsignedLong.fromLongBits(value).doubleValue(); // 1.8446744073709552E19
```

Internally, this works as follows ([see the source of `UnsignedLong`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/0a2258e/guava/src/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLong.java)):

```
double dValue = (double) (value & 0x7fffffffffffffffL);
if (value < 0) {
    dValue += 0x1.0p63;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a long that's supposed to be interpreted as unsigned you can do the following:

```
long v = Long.MAX_VALUE+1;
double d = ((double)(v>>>1))*2+(v&1);
```

You right-shift the long (ignore the sign) which is equivalent to dividing by two the unsigned number, turn that to double and then multiply by two to correct back (now as a double), then add back the bit you dropped.